# How to solve $ (x + 2y - 4)dx - (2x + y - 5)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the differential equation $(x + 2y - 4)dx - (2x + y - 5)dy = 0$. It's not separable, nor exact nor homogeneous. The solution is $(x - y -1)^3 = C(x + y - 3)$. How can I achieve it?

The other equations similar to this are:

$(1+ x + y)dy - (1- 3x - 3y)dx = 0$
Answer: $3x + y + 2ln(-x - y +1) = k$

$(3x - y + 2)dx + (9x - 3y +1)dy = 0$
Answer: $2x + 6y + C = ln(6x - 2y +1)$

If someone point me out how to solve the first equation I will be likely to solve the others. Thank you very much.

Update: Given Orangutango and Chris help I moved to a solvable d.e. But didn't get the same answer my professor listed. Did I miss some step?

(X + 2Y)dX = (2X+Y)dY
dY/dX = (X + 2Y)/(2X + Y)

Making a substitution to solve the now homogenous:
Y = VX, Y'= V + V'X

V+V'X = (X + 2VX)/(2X + VX)
V+V'X = (1 + 2V)/(2 + V)
V'X = ((1 + 2V)/(2 + V)) - V
V'X = (1 - V^2)/(2 + V)

(2 + V)dV/(1-V^2) = dX/X

Integrating the left side I got:

int (2 + V)dV/1-V^2 =
2 * int dV / (1-V^2) + int V dV / (1-V^2) =
log | (v + 1) / (v-1) | - 1/2 log | V^2 + 1 | + c1

Integrating the right side:
log X + c2

Then replacing V=Y/X and then X=x-2 and Y=y-1 don't seems to yield the proposed answers. Where did my professor got this? Is the above solution correct? Thanks again.

Comment: $(1 + 2V)/(2 + V) - V\ne(1 + 2V)/(2 + V)$

Comment: Yep, I copied it wrong. Updated, thanks.

Comment: Hey Ricardo, check out my edits. I think your teacher is correct ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$  (x + 2y - 4)dx - (2x + y - 5)dy = 0 $$

Let $X = x + a$ and $Y= y+ b$ and let's see if we can choose suitable values for $a$ and $b$.

$$ (X - a + 2Y - 2b - 4)dX - (2X-2a + Y - b - 5)dY =0$$

It's easy to find what the "suitable" values should be, since we just want them to cancel out the constants! So we solve the following system of equations:

$$\begin{align*}
-4 &= a + 2b\\
-5 &= 2a + b
\end{align*}$$
I'll let you verify that the correct values are $a=-2$ and $b=-1$. This leaves us with
$$(X + 2Y)dX - (2X+Y)dY=0$$
Can you take it from here?

**EDIT**: Now let $Y=VX$, and hence $dY = VdX + XdV$.
$$\begin{align*}
X(1 + 2V)dX - X(2+V)(VdX+XdV) &=0\\
X(1-V^2)dX - X^2(2+V)dV &=0\\
X(1-V^2)dX &= X^2(2+V)dV\\
\dfrac{1}{X}dX &= \dfrac{2+V}{1-V^2}dV\\
\log(X) + C_1 &= \dfrac{1}{2}(-3 \log(1-V)+\log(1+V))\\
C_2X^2 &= \dfrac{1+V}{(1-V)^3}\\
C_2X^2(1-V)^3 &= 1+V\\
C_2X^2(1-\dfrac{Y}{X})^3 &= 1+\dfrac{Y}{X}\\
C_2\dfrac{(X-Y)^3}{X}&= 1+\dfrac{Y}{X}\\
C_2(X-Y)^3 &= X + Y\\
C_2(x-y-1)^3 &= x + y - 3
\end{align*}$$

So your teacher has the correct solution.

Comment: Thank you Orangutango, with your help I was able to solve the d.e. But didn't match with the professor answer. Would you take a look at it? Thanks again

Comment: I think the trickiest part for me was the integration of (2+V)/(1-V^2)DV. I split in two different integrals 2/(1-v^2) + v/(1-v^2). The former yields log V+1/V-1 and the latter -1/2 log |v^2 + 1|. How did you manage to get (1/2 * (-3 log(1-V) + log(1+V) )?

Comment: Actually, the former yields $\log((V+1)/(1-V)) = \log(V+1) - \log(1-V)$ and the latter yields $-1/2\log(1-V^2) = -1/2\log((1-V)(1+V)) = -1/2(\log(V+1) + \log(1-V))$. Taking the sum gives us $\log(V+1) - \log(1-V) - 1/2(\log(V+1) + \log(1-V)) = 1/2(\log(V+1) - 3\log(1-V))$

Comment: You're right Orangutango! Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

It's only those pesky constants $-4$ and $-5$ that are keeping the equation from being homogeneous. They can be eliminated by an appropriately chosen substitution $X=x+a$, $Y=y+b$ (so that $\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{dy}{dx}$) to give a homogeneous equation which you can then solve as normal.